# reload supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow or allow MPMoviePlayerViewController in landscape mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, orientation

I want to play movie with MPMoviePlayerViewController in my portrait-only app. So, I do like this.

```
- (NSUInteger) application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {

    if ([[window.rootViewController presentedViewController] isKindOfClass:[MPMoviePlayerViewController class]]) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
    }
    else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
}
```

As a result, I can play in landscape mode. However, when I dismiss that my app is in Landscape mode. So, is there a way to change my app to portrait mode dynamically in **supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow**. I know I can get notification when MPMoviePlayerViewController exit. But I don't know how to set my app back to portrait only back when it exit.

Answer (score 0):

1) Set Device Orientation: Portrait Mode only.

2) After that, go your ViewController.m class (where you want to show the MPMoviePlayerViewController), and add this notification:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];                    //Get the device object
    [device beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];         //Tell it to start monitoring the accelerometer for orientation

    NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];    //Get the notification centre for the app
    [nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged:) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:device];
}

- (void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)note{
    UIDeviceOrientation devOrientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;
    if (devOrientation==4||devOrientation==3){
        //Now rotate the frame of your MPMoviePlayerViewController for Landscape mode
        [movieController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width)];
        [movieController.view setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI_2)];

        CGRect slFr6=movieController.view.frame;
        slFr6.origin.x=0;
        slFr6.origin.y=0;
        movieController.view.frame=slFr6;
    }
    else if (devOrientation==1||devOrientation==2){
        ////Now rotate the frame of your MPMoviePlayerViewController for Portrait mode
        [movieController.view setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0)];
        [movieController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

        CGRect slFr6=movieController.view.frame;
        slFr6.origin.x=0;
        slFr6.origin.y=0;
        movieController.view.frame=slFr6;
    }
}

//For Adding MPMoviePlayerController use it
-(void)createPlayer{
    MPMoviePlayerController *movieController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
    movieController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;//MPMovieControlStyleNone;
    [movieController setContentURL:_url];
    [movieController.view setFrame:CGRectMake (0,0,self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    [self.view addSubview:movieController.view];
    [movieController prepareToPlay];
    [movieController play];
}
```

Comment: Thanks you for detail answer. May I know how to do if it is open like this?     MPMoviePlayerViewController *mp = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]
               initWithContentURL:url];
    
[self.navigationController presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mp];

Comment: You can use MPMoviePlayerController for it.

Comment: yes. But Can I use "presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated" instead of adding subview?

Comment: I think, You can't rotate the MPMoviePlayerViewController by using Notification.